# Android SDK Auto Import Problems

Tags: android, sdk, shortcut

Im following Google's guide on how to "make android apps" and came [this far](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) before I hit some problems. When trying to either use the Android SDK shortcut Alt + Enter or importing it manually. When i press Alt + Enter a little box comes up where it just says "Create Test". I've tried looking around the net, but haven't found any similar problems... Here is my code in

MyActivity.java file:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
      EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
}
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare `public void sendMessage(View view) {...}` inside your class.

It should look like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
public void sendMessage(View view) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
      EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
}
...
```

I dont want to offend you, but maybe you should take some basic Java lessons before diving into Android, that can help prevent this kind of error.

Comment: No offense taken ! :) And I think youre right I'll get back to android after I've learned some basic Java. Thanks for answering my question so fast.